# wordpress - 404 page not found after updating permalinks w Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I changed my permalinks structure to use the postname
I restarted Nginx to clear the cache, but even if I can display my homepage, when I hit any oage link , I get a 404 page not found ...

Using Nginx , I don't have to update the .htaccess file , but should I update my site Nginx conf file ...

here is the location section used with .php

```
      location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params; }
```

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a complete file section! server { } is missing.

Use this one but use this one between server { } and should work

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params; 
}
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

updated the /location   to

```
 location / {
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
```

working fine now ...

Comment: Upvoted, also: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`